# Prevent users from modifying Perl script

Tags: perl, security

I am using Perl PAR module for packaging my applications written in Perl. As a security request, I'd like to prevent users from modifying the scripts. Is it possible to do this within the PAR module, or is there any other way of achiving this?

Comment: Here is a useful discussion of some approaches and their limitations: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=848604. Ultimately you can't prevent users from getting at your code, but you can make it more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious way would be to modify the security on the script to only allow users that you want (or in a certain group) write permissions.

In Linux, you could use chmod 755 [filename].  That would give the script owner read, write and execute permission, and everyone else read and execute (so they could run it).  If you want a more specific answer, please let us know what your exact goal is.  Is only a specific group supposed to be able to read and execute this script, too?

Comment: Hmmmm...if they can read it, they can copy it to a new file then modify it to their heart's content!

Comment: Sure.  You're absolutely right.  But I'm assuming that the PAM user set up is important with running the script, which is why he doesn't want users running this script, particularly (maybe, for instance, the script's owner is root).  In that case, a user copying it to another file wouldn't have the permissions to run said copied script and affect whatever it is affecting.  There are a lot of questions, which is why I asked for more information. :)

Comment: They can still hot patch the script using `perl -e'...overrides some builtins...; do "script.pl" or die $@'`. They could even tell Perl to autoload a module that will hook into its parser and change how the script is parsed. (Minus the autoloading, this is how my module [Syntax::Feature::Loop](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax::Feature::Loop) works.)

Comment: I guess obfuscation is a better solution.  Lol.  Bottom line is, like dan said, it's a scripting language, and therefore there's no real way to keep people from the code.  But, if you have users with that kind of malicious intent with access to your servers, you have another problem entirely.